# How do I "measure" the performance of a time-series forecasting code in Keras?

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series, keras, forecasting

I am very new to the doing time-series forecasting in Keras. For the problem I am working on, I want to know how well my model is performing. I would like to know of some best practices for accomplishing this task. Please advise, and thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is too broad, you have to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to look for the `accuracy` and `loss` of your model:

```
model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)
eval_loss, eval_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_set, test_set,
                                          batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
print("Accuracy: {:.2f}%".format(eval_accuracy * 100))
print("Loss: {}".format(eval_loss))
```

You can even plot a diagram to see the loss and accuracy during training:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
history = model.fit(...)        

summarize history for accuracy 
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

# summarize history for loss
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

**EDIT**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Series', 'Scale Signal'])

history = model.fit(...)
predicted = model.predict(test_input)

df_val_loss = pd.DataFrame(history.history['val_loss'])
df_val_loss.plot()

df_predicted = pd.DataFrame(predicted).T
df_predicted.columns = ['Predicted']

df_result = pd.concat([df, df_predicted], ignore_index=True)
df_result.plot()

plt.show()
```

The above script gets and plot predicted data and the validation loss. I don't work with time series too often so I can't give you any advice from my experience but here are a few good links that I hope can help you out:

- [Evaluating forecast accuracy](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/5)
- [Time Series Forecasting Performance Measures With Python](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-performance-measures-with-python/)
- [How to best evaluate a time series prediction algorithm?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/175714/188924)

Comment: This assumes classification, which might not be the case.

Comment: Hi Huy, my problem is not a classification problem. I am dealing with a time-series forecasting problem. I wanted to know if there are good practices I should follow to check if the model is working as it should. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer here. For a regression problem that I am working on Dr. Brownlee explains three ways: Mean Absolute Error, Mean Squared Error, and R^2: [LINK](https://machinelearningmastery.com/metrics-evaluate-machine-learning-algorithms-python/) This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks to all for the help and the negative points!